# How can you find your correct size of cricket bat?

Tags: cricket, equipment

What is the best way to determine what cricket bat size to use? This is a general question but my specific case is for my 8 year old son.

Comment: PS: can someone with enough cred please create tags for `cricket-batting`, `cricket-bowling` and `cricket-fielding` and then apply the first of these to **this** question??

Comment: Nope. Let's keep an eye on what we [create tags](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/312/grounds-of-tag-creation) for.

Comment: @hims056 - ok. I guess it makes sense if these labels don't have the volume that SO labels get (even though people **should** be talking more about cricket).

Comment: @Scotty.NET It's not even that. Sure, if the question merits the reasonable scope and usefulness of the tag, but your question is *not about* the act of cricket batting. It is about how to select a bat (a piece of equipment) to use for batting in cricket. FYI, cricket is the most talked about sport on Sports SE.

Comment: @Scotty.NET people certainly **should** be talking more about cricket, agreed! Signs are good on this site, happily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question. A common mistake is to select a bat that is too big for a young player. The temptation may be to buy a large bat for the player to "grow into", to save money as much as anything else, but it's definitely not a good idea. The bat should feel comfortable to and manoeuvrable by the player.

*Bob Woolmer's Art and Science of Cricket* has this to say on choosing a bat for a young player (p.101):

> The ideal length for a bat is the inside measurement of the batsman's trousers [...]. Bats that come up to a boy's hip or waist will do irreparable damage to his technique - not to mention his pleasure and interest in the game.
>
> The weight of the bat must also be carefully considered [...] children over the age of seven fare best with bats that weigh no more than a kilogram. A good yardstick is to ask the child to lift the bat in his non-dominant hand (i.e., his left hand if he is right-handed), and to hold it out horizontally with his shoulder for one minute. If he can do this without strain or difficulty, the weight is correct.

Personally, I would err on the side of caution and opt for a bat that is lighter rather than heavier. The last thing one wants is a bat that impedes the development of good technique.

Comment: +1 for erring on the side of a lighter bat if there is some uncertainty.

Comment: +1 for a great answer beyond a simple table. I will check out the book you have referenced, sounds very good.

Comment: @Scotty.NET Thanks, it's not a particularly cheap volume but it's great value in my opinion. Huge amount of fascinating information and insights on the game.

Comment: @Spinner - I now have a copy of _Woolmer_, it is **huge**.. it will make good bed time reading for my son (poor kid).